# Restricting access to geoserver module

Tags: geoserver, java

I built an extension module for Geoserver 2.5 using Maven and Wicket. It places a Label to the left of the navigation list that calls a HTML-Page in Geoserver when clicked. It looks and works as it should; the problem is that it is visible and usable without login.

How can I configure my extension module/GeoServer so that it gets to the plugin only after login?

Answer (score 1):

Your pages must extend GeoServerSecuredPage to be visible only to administrators.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, I changed class extend from GeoServerBasePage to GeoServerSecuredPage and tried to build but Failed, of course: I had to change import org.geoserver.web.GeoServerSecuredPage; too, then it worked and now everyone behaves just fine ;-)